# Can QueueTrigger function have response as controller

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

is it possible to have from QueueTrigger function response as controller? When I call a get method from controller response body could be something like

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "The resource does not exist",
...
```

Is there a way to do similar response from the function? I found only output binding where it can return string to another queue, but this is not what I am looking for:

```
[FunctionName("QueueOutput")]
[return: Queue("myqueue-items")]
public static string Run([HttpTrigger] dynamic input,  ILogger log)
{
    ...
}
```

If I do this:

```
[FunctionName("QueueOutput")]
public static Task<string> Run([HttpTrigger] dynamic input,  ILogger log)
{
    ...
    return "...";
}
```

I have following error:

```
The 'CleanDataFunction' function is in error: 
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'CleanDataFunction'. 
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter '$return' to type 
String&. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If 
you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, 
etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) 
in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), 
builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is not possible. Found answer here:
[Azure Function doesn't work with QueueTrigger and non-void return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218969/azure-function-doesnt-work-with-queuetrigger-and-non-void-return-value)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create the json you need, either manually as a string or using JSON.NET, and return it serialized.

Comment: Yeah, I already tried it `Task<string>`, but I get an following error : `The 'CleanDataFunction' function is in error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'CleanDataFunction'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter '$return' to type String&. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).`